# how to port java inner function in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, inner-classes

How can I port a java inner function from [here](https://github.com/DataSystemsLab/GeoSpark/blob/master/src/main/java/org/datasyslab/geospark/spatialOperator/JoinQuery.java#L81-L95) 
which fully is contained in to Scala?

```
JavaPairRDD<Envelope, HashSet<Point>> castedResult = joinListResultAfterAggregation.mapValues(new Function<HashSet<Geometry>,HashSet<Point>>()
            {
                @Override
                public HashSet<Point> call(HashSet<Geometry> spatialObjects) throws Exception {
                    HashSet<Point> castedSpatialObjects = new HashSet<Point>();
                    Iterator spatialObjectIterator = spatialObjects.iterator();
                    while(spatialObjectIterator.hasNext())
                    {
                        castedSpatialObjects.add((Point)spatialObjectIterator.next());
                    }
                    return castedSpatialObjects;
                }

            });
            return castedResult;
```

My approach as outlined below would not compile due to some `NotinferredU`

```
val castedResult = joinListResultAfterAggregation.mapValues(new Function[java.util.HashSet[Geometry], java.util.HashSet[Point]]() {
    def call(spatialObjects: java.util.HashSet[Geometry]): java.util.HashSet[Point] = {
      val castedSpatialObjects = new java.util.HashSet[Point]
      val spatialObjectIterator = spatialObjects.iterator
      while (spatialObjectIterator.hasNext) castedSpatialObjects.add(spatialObjectIterator.next.asInstanceOf[Point])
      castedSpatialObjects
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking a question about compilation errors please provide the exact error, especially when your code doesn't stand on its own.

The inner function itself is fine; my guess would be that due to changes above `joinListResultAfterAggregation` isn't a `JavaPairRDD` anymore, but a normal `RDD[(Envelope, Something)]` (where `Something` could be `java.util.HashSet`, `scala.collection.Set` or some subtype), so its `mapValues` takes a Scala function, not a `org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function`. Scala functions are written as lambdas: `spatialObjects: Something => ...` (the body will depend on what `Something` actually is, and the argument type can be omitted in some circumstances).

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
val castedResult = joinListResultAfterAggregation.mapValues(spatialObjects => {
                        spatialObjects.map(obj => (Point) obj)
                   })
```